# Fetch user details from another model

Tags: django, flutter, dart, django-rest-framework

I have a model(Poll) which contains another model(User) with user details.
I want to get the Username of who posted a poll

but the below is error occurred

```
I/flutter (21892): type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

this is my model class(flutter)

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Poll {
  Poll({
    required this.id,
    required this.choices,
    required this.question,
    required this.pubDate,
    required this.createdBy,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final List<Choices> choices;
  late final String question;
  late final String pubDate;
  late final User createdBy;

  Poll.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    choices =
        List.from(json['choices']).map((e) => Choices.fromJson(e)).toList();
    question = json['question'];
    pubDate = json['pub_date'];
    createdBy = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(json['created_by']));
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['choices'] = choices.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    _data['question'] = question;
    _data['pub_date'] = pubDate;
    _data['created_by'] = createdBy.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Choices {
  Choices({
    required this.id,
    required this.choiceText,
    required this.poll,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final String choiceText;
  late final int poll;

  Choices.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    choiceText = json['choice_text'];
    poll = json['poll'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['choice_text'] = choiceText;
    _data['poll'] = poll;
    return _data;
  }
}

class User {
  User({
    required this.id,
    required this.password,
    required this.lastLogin,
    required this.isSuperuser,
    required this.username,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.email,
    required this.isStaff,
    required this.isActive,
    required this.dateJoined,
    required this.groups,
    required this.userPermissions,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final String password;
  late final String lastLogin;
  late final bool isSuperuser;
  late final String username;
  late final String firstName;
  late final String lastName;
  late final String email;
  late final bool isStaff;
  late final bool isActive;
  late final String dateJoined;
  late final List<dynamic> groups;
  late final List<dynamic> userPermissions;

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    password = json['password'];
    lastLogin = json['last_login'];
    isSuperuser = json['is_superuser'];
    username = json['username'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    email = json['email'];
    isStaff = json['is_staff'];
    isActive = json['is_active'];
    dateJoined = json['date_joined'];
    groups = List.castFrom<dynamic, dynamic>(json['groups']);
    userPermissions = List.castFrom<dynamic, dynamic>(json['user_permissions']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['password'] = password;
    _data['last_login'] = lastLogin;
    _data['is_superuser'] = isSuperuser;
    _data['username'] = username;
    _data['first_name'] = firstName;
    _data['last_name'] = lastName;
    _data['email'] = email;
    _data['is_staff'] = isStaff;
    _data['is_active'] = isActive;
    _data['date_joined'] = dateJoined;
    _data['groups'] = groups;
    _data['user_permissions'] = userPermissions;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

here is how I am parsing the json

```
List<Poll> _polls = [];

  Future<bool> getOffers() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(polls_uri);

    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      var data = json.decode(response.body);

      List<Poll> temp = [];

      for (var element in data) {
        Poll poll = Poll.fromJson(element);
        temp.add(poll);
      }

      _polls = temp;
      
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    }
  }

  List<Poll> get polls {
    return [..._polls];
  }
```

this is where i want to display I want to display the details

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: polls.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(polls[index].question),
                      Text(polls[index].createdBy.username),
                    ]),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

my model class(django)

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

serializer

```
class PollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required = False)

    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = '__all__'


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

views

```
class PollList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Poll.objects.all() [:20]
    serializer_class = PollSerializer
```

Poll Json data: the key "created_by" is a model of class user... It is from the class I want to get the username

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "choices": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "choice_text": "Day",
                "poll": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "choice_text": "Boarding",
                "poll": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "choice_text": "Mixed",
                "poll": 3
            }
        ],
        "created_by": 1,
        "question": "Type of School: Day or Boarding",
        "pub_date": "2022-07-21T13:29:23.445097Z"
    },
```

Comment: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' is a typecast error. May be one of your note in json response is int but your variable is String.

Comment: Yes, The int value is a primary key of a model

Comment: Share an example of json data.

Comment: I've added the  poll JSON data